# How to resolve No ad config issue in android Admob?

Tags: java, android, xml, admob, ads

Hello I am trying to use Admob ads on my app but ads are not displaying. I am getting this error:

```
"Code": 3,
  "Message": "No ad config.",
  "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
  "Cause": "null",
  "Response Info": {
    "Response ID": "null",
    "Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
    "Adapter Responses": []
  }
```

The same error occurs with test ids as well.

This is gradle implementation:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.3.0'
```

I initialize ads like so:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this);
```

This is interstitial initialization:

```
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        InterstitialAd.load(c,c.getString(R.string.popup), adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;

            }
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                mInterstitialAd = null;

            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure that you completed the configuration as said in the doc [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#configure_your_app), especially step 3? Do you get this error when you initialise the SDK, on the interstitial loading request or when you call the `show(...)` on the interstitial instance? Are you sure that you are using the correct `unitId`?

Comment: Yes I followed the documentation, the unitId is correct as well. This error occurs on interstitial loading.

Comment: Have you tried to setup an app-ads.txt  file as said [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762)?

Comment: Yes I have created app-ads.txt on the server

Comment: Could it be that you should use the `AdManagerAdRequest` as said in the reference of the `AdRequest` [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest)?

Comment: I contacted Admob team, it was a Privacy Policy, issue that's way ads were not showing. Thank you for trying to help me though.

Comment: I think your device Id is changed an you are running ads on Debug Build. Check for Device Id in logs and Replace it in your current Configuration .

Comment: Besart which type of privacy policy issue ? i am facing same issue please help to resolve it

Comment: @Binesh Kumar Make sure you are not violating any AdMob policies otherwise ads won't show up. You can check this on Policy Center page on AdMob or contact their team.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Besart, you saved my life. some of our games are designed for children below 12, so we have to show DFF ads. following code is important:

```sh
  // String MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G = "G";
  // String MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_PG = "PG";
  // String MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_T = "T";
  // String MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_MA = "MA";
  // int TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE = 1;
  // int TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_FALSE = 0;

RequestConfiguration configuration = new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(1)
        .setMaxAdContentRating("G")
        .build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

But the code will cause "no ad config" error on test ads. So, pls delete the code above if you have, hope helpful.

Comment: If you run your app without the above code, you can find this line in your run window: I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("<here you will see your device id>")) to get test ads on this device.
Add the following code:

List<String> testDeviceIds = List.of("<your device id>");
RequestConfiguration configuration= new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
    .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(1)
    .setMaxAdContentRating("G")
    .setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds)
    .build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);

This worked fine for me.